# Defining controllers using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating web application using Angular js in ES6. I just started learning angular. I have following questions which I couldn't understand much from resources in internet.

1) I am using ui-router for routing based on states. I have following code in my controller

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home);
        $stateProvider
            .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'contact.html',
           controller: myContactController
        });
};
```

Contact.html:

```
<div ng-controller=”myContactController”>
….
</div>
```

Question:

a) I have specified the controller in my state in js. Should I need to specify the controller using ng-controller in my view also? What is the difference and why its necessary ?

2)  I have a base module for my app.

Base module - Index.js :

```
import subapp1 from  ‘./subApp1/index’;
angular.module(“myapp”,[subapp1]);
```

subApp1/index.js

```
Export default function(){
Angular. module(“subApp1”,[]);
};
```

Question:
a)  Is this the right way of injecting sub module dependency in to base module?If not which is the best way to inject module dependency in to base module?
b)  I would appreciate if I can get best links to understand dependency injection and different scopes in angular js in basic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have specified the controller in my state in js. Should I need to specify the controller using ng-controller in my view also? What is the difference and why its necessary ?

You don't need to use `ngController` in HTML. Router will fetch HTML template and compile it with specified controller.

> I have a base module for my app...

You specify dependent module by its name, so your setup could look like this (note, how you export `name` property of the Angular module):

```
export default angular.module('subApp1', [])
  .factory('someService', semeService) // For example, attach some module service
  .directive('someDirective', someDirective) // ... or some components
  .name;
```

and then

```
import subapp1 from './subApp1/index';
import subapp2 from './subApp2/index';

angular.module('myapp', [
  subapp1,
  subapp2
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.a) no, you shouldn't. If you do, you'll have two instances of the controller

2.a) no. First you don't "inject" a module into another module: a module depends on another one, that's all. That has nothing to do with dependency injection. And the syntax for that is

```
angular.module('myapp', ['subApp1']);
```

I.e. the elements of the array must be **names** of module you depend on. And of course, these modules must themselves be defined (before or after, it doesn't matter), using

```
 angular.module('subApp1', []);
```

2.b) https://docs.angularjs.org/guide